# Unordered_set insertion worst case

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

I have a question about insertion in unordered_set. I want to build an example of worst case insertion. I have 30000 strings(len string <= 16, possible characters are english letters uppercase or lowercase and symbol "_"). So i have 53^16 words, and i have to choose 30000 string to build worst case insertion. I knew that unordered_set uses std::hash for hashing, and i tried to sort out words with len = 3, and calculate their hashes. I get, that each hash is different, so i cant build words with len = 3 with same hashes to build worst case insertion example? So what can i do?

Comment: To build a worst case insertion example you have to have knowledge of the hash function.

Comment: @101010 i understand it, but what are other variants of solving this problem.

Comment: Tony answered your question. Another way a little bit anorthodox, is to use [std::unordered_set::hash_function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/hash_function/) and generate a test set that has identical hash values.

Comment: @101010 I understant that too, i tried too build worst case, using unordered_set::hash_function, and for all words with length <= 3 with rules that i had written in topic, all hashes are different. So my question is about how to get same hashes :D

Comment: See how good the STL programmers are :P. Follow Tony's answer.

Comment: @101010 any links on STL implementations ?

Comment: Look for `std::hash<>` `std::string` specialization in GCC I think is in `functional_hash.h`. Good luck though :)

Answer (score 3):

`std::hash` implementations vary - the Standard lets the compiler vendor do whatever they think sensible.  So, it's easiest to get worst case behaviour by specifying your own hash routine when you instantiate the `unordered_set`: it can just return the same value (e.g. 0) for all input values.

```
struct Hash
{
    size_t operator()(const std::string&) const { return 0; }
};

std::unordered_set<string, Hash> my_set;
```

Comment: I should use default unordered_set::hash_function, and i have to build tests, not hash_foo that gives me worst case.

Comment: @thmw: you'd better study your Standard Library `std::hash<std::string>` implementation then... and good luck - it may well be very tricky!

Comment: can you give me link to STL implementation, or where i can find it? Ty

Comment: @thmw Just `echo "#include <unordered_set>" > x.cpp` then invoke your compiler with whatever its preprocess-only argument is... e.g. for GCC `g++ -E x.cpp`, for VC++ `cl /E x.cpp` - redirect the output to `less`, `more` or a file and use your editor of choice.  You'll see the hash implementations in there.